# Azure cloud service architecture design

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

We are facing some architecture design choice about multiple web roles, here is our requirement:

- There are two Web Roles in our Cloud Service solution, one is pure MVC project which for our website portal, and the other one is pure Web API which for the data service exposed the RESTful api
- We prefer our MVC project be very lightweight, and on the other hand out Web API project can be scaled up/out very flexibly
- Due to the usability, we hope the Web API use the 443 port for HTTPS. But our MVC also need HTTPS and of course it also need port 443

So in our opinion, the latter two requirements are in conflict, since we have to deploy to separate web roles to satisfy the Web API scale, and we should use the individual web role to [use the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733640/use-subpath-for-two-web-applications-hosted-in-one-web-role) .

Are the opinions correct? And if we want to achieve both, moving Web API to another service (Cloud Service or Web Site) is the only choice we can make?

Any further question is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each WebRole is a dedicated VM of sorts.

As per the [blog post](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/) you've linked to in your prev post, from an iis perspective this is something similar to the following:

```
.<root>                                     
   |                                        
   |                                        
   +---App1 (http://contoso.com/app1)       
          |                                 
          |                                 
          +---App2 (http://contoso.com/app1/app2)
```

And your requirement is to scale out app2 alone -> this is not possible.

You need to have two different webroles to handle this scenario.

Comment: App2 cannot be scaled alone. App1 also gets scaled. You have to separate them to two different WebRoles